# multivalue report parameter selection checkboxes disabled ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have a problem in my ASP.net application.

I open a report in reportviewer, which contains a multivalue parameter, and I am only able to see the values, not click on them to select or deselect.

Does anyone know what can cause this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had my reportviewer property enabled set to false...